# Request body return empty value when using ContentCachingRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used ContentCachingRequestWrapper to read and log my http input request body as a String. But it seems no working.

I'm building a Spring Boot project and it include logging request mechanism. I used `@Aspect` to log any request from my Controller. There are is a problem here, HttpServletRequest is an interface which exposes `getInputStream()`  method to read the body. By default the data from this InputStream can be read only once. So i following `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` to wrap `HttpServletRequest` and read many time. But it doesn't seem to work, i tried to convert `requestWrapper.getReader()` to String but still return empty String. I used another way like create new class and extend `HttpServletRequestWrapper` but it doesn't get any better. Any one have any idea for this problem.
I followed this solution:

AppFilter.class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class AppFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(currentRequest);

        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

RequestLogger.class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Aspect
@Component
@Log4j2
public class RequestLogger {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Loggers)")
    public void webLog() {
    }

    @Before("webLog()")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "webLog()", returning = "ret")
    public void doAfterReturning(Object ret) {
    }

    @Around("webLog()")
    public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object response = joinPoint.proceed();
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (attributes == null) {
            return response;
        }
        HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();

        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) signature;
        Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();

        this.log(joinPoint, request, method, response);
        return response;
    }

    private void log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest request, Method method, Object response) {
        RequestInfo requestInfo = this.getRequestInfo(joinPoint, request, method, response);
        String requestBody = "";
        try {
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
            requestBody = requestWrapper.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")); //empty string here
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResponseEntity res = (ResponseEntity) response;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String message = String.format("Done %s to %s with status %s request: %s response: %s",
                requestInfo.getRequestMethod(),
                requestInfo.getRequestPath(),
                requestInfo.getResponseStatus(),
                requestBody,
                gson.toJson(res.getBody())
        );
        doLog(requestInfo, message);
    }

    @NotNull
    private RequestInfo getRequestInfo(
            ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Method method,
            Object response
    ) {
        //format request
    }

    private Object getParameter(Method method, Object[] args) {
        //reading request parameter
    }

    private void doLog(RequestInfo requestInfo, String message) {
        //logging process
    }
```

When i send a POST request with content body and its my log. You can see my response still ok but my request has empty value.

```
2023-04-19 09:12:12.517  INFO 12548 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] v.k.infrastructure.logger.RequestLogger  : Done POST to /api/v1/sms/invitation with status 200 request:  response: {"message":"OK","code":200,"timeStamp":1681870332503}
```

Comment: In terms of design, it seems you are trying to both use a filter and Aspect at the same time, but you probably only want to use one or the other.

Comment: That being said, you might want to first try taking out the usage of ContentCachingRequestWrapper and see if the response is still empty just to make sure that creating the AppFilter component isn't breaking the filter chain in some way.